# How to dim the device backlight using libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, android, screen

I have an idea for a very minimalistic game. To fit in with this theme. I want no explicit messages or tutorials etc. I want to experiment with ways to very gently, implicitly prompt the player to touch the screen.

My idea is to turn off the phone backlight, to mimic what happens when your phone screen is about to turn off due to inactivity. Hopefully, this will make the player think the screen is about to turn off and make them tap the screen - so mission accomplished, I will have subtly prompted the player to touch the screen.

Now, obviously I don't want to turn the screen off, I want to dim the backlight, or maybe trick the phone into thinking it has been inactive for the right amount of time. I know I can just make the displayed image on the screen darker, but that would not accurately mimic the backlight becoming dimmer.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a gamedev-specific issue. It's a general question about the Android API. I would recommend to post this question on https://stackoverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting `LayoutParams` on your Android `Window` where you specifiy `screenBrightness`.

If you define some interface in your **core** like:

```
public interface WindowController {
    void setBrightness(float factor);
}
```

And take a reference to that in the constructor of your game-class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    WindowController windowController;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    public MyGdxGame(WindowController windowController) {
        this.windowController = windowController;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched() && windowController != null)
            windowController.setBrightness(0.2f);

        ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Then, in your `AndroidLauncher` in **android** you implement that interface and call
`setAttributes` with updated `LayoutParams`:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements WindowController {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBrightness(final float factor) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
                layoutParams.screenBrightness = factor;
                getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            }
        });
    }
}
```